# Javascript Smallest Number in 3 Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can figure out iterating through an array for similar numbers, but creating a function in order to do so through 3 arrays is stumping me for some reason. For the assignment I need to limit my built in functions to indexOf and .length.

For example:

```
var sample = [1,2,3,5,6], [2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7,8]

function smallestCommonNumber(arr1, arr2, arr3){

}
```

I will need this function to iterate through the three ascending arrays and return the smallest of any pairs (must match all 3 arrays) and if not, return false. I know that using indexOf will return a specified item, but how would I use that for an unspecified array?

Comment: `sample` isn't valid - if you have three separate arrays it'll work.

Comment: I understand if the function was called such as: smallestCommonNumber([1,2,3,4],[4,1,6,7],[4,9,1,2]) it would work, but I need to create the function to sort through and find the common number and decide which is the smallest and return that.

Comment: Alright - I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the 3 arrays are sorted in *ascending* order you can iterate over all 3 arrays from left to right using 3 pointers until you get a number that occurs in all 3 arrays, and just return that number since that will be guaranteed to be the smallest:

```js
function smallestCommonNumber(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    let i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length && k < arr3.length) {
        if (arr1[i] === arr2[j] && arr2[j] === arr3[k]) {
            return arr1[i];
        } else if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            i++;
        } else if (arr2[j] < arr3[k]) {
            j++;
        } else {
            k++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6];
const a2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const a3 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

// Assumes a1, a2, and a3 are sorted in ascending order
console.log(smallestCommonNumber(a1, a2, a3));
```

As requested by **[@kinduser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6695924/kind-user)** in the comments here is a solution that works with unsorted arrays as well:

```js
function smallestCommonNumber(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    const set1 = new Set(arr1);
    const set2 = new Set(arr2);
    const intersection1 = new Set([...set1].filter(n => set2.has(n)));
    if (!intersection1.size) {
        return false;
    }
    const set3 = new Set(arr3);
    const intersection2 = new Set([...intersection1].filter(n => set3.has(n)));
    return intersection2.size ? Math.min(...intersection2) : false;
}

const a1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6];
const a2 = [2, 5, 4, 3, 6];
const a3 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

console.log(smallestCommonNumber(a1, a2, a3));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Happy to help, this is a common interview question.

Comment: Same here, it will fail if numbers are not ordered.

Comment: @kinduser the question states "three ***ascending*** arrays", which implies they are sorted/ordered.

Comment: Yeah I know, thats why I upvoted. But still would love to see a solution that works for disordered aswell.

Comment: @kinduser Updated the answer with a solution that works for disordered aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the arrays are *sorted with ascending* values as specified in the question.

Iterate each number in one of the arrays and check if it exists in both of the other arrays using `indexOf`, if not found it will return -1, here using `~` operator to shift -1 to 0 to get a falsy value.
Could just as well just check `.indexOf(..) > -1`.

```js
function smallestCommonNumber(arr1, arr2, arr3){
  for (const number of arr1) {
    if (~arr2.indexOf(number) && ~arr3.indexOf(number)) {
      return number;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(smallestCommonNumber([1,2,3,5,6], [2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7,8]));
```

For a version that finds the smallest number without ascending arrays:

```js
function smallestCommonNumber(arr1, arr2, arr3){
  let smallest = null;
  for (const number of arr1) {
    if (~arr2.indexOf(number) && ~arr3.indexOf(number)) {
      smallest = number < smallest ? number : smallest ?? number;
    }
  }

  return smallest ?? false;
}

console.log(smallestCommonNumber([6,5,3,2,1], [2,3,4,5,6], [4,5,6,7,8]));
```

Comment: I gave you an upvote but realized this will fail if numbers are not ordered :(

Comment: @kinduser yes it will indeed fail then, would need to be done differently if the input isn't as convenient as specified here! Could collect all common numbers then find the smallest one.

Comment: @kinduser think the alternative version should work fine :) its a bit dirty with the one liner tho

Answer (score 0):

```
var sample1 = [1,2,3,5,6]
var sample2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
var sample3 = [4,5,6,7,8]

function smallestCommonNumber(...arrays){
  const smallestsOfAllArrays = []
  arrays.forEach(array => {    
    smallestsOfAllArrays.push(smallestOfOneArray(array))
  })
  return smallestOfOneArray(smallestsOfAllArrays)
}

function smallestOfOneArray(oneArray){
  return oneArray.reduce((acm, value) => acm <= value ? acm : value)
}

console.log(smallestCommonNumber(sample1, sample2, sample3))
//1
```

Answer (score -1):

Do like:

```js
function inArray(value, array){
  if(array.indexOf(value) === -1){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function least(){
  let a = [...arguments], l = a.length, q = l-1, r = [];
  for(let i=0,b; i<l; i++){
    b = a[i];
    for(let n=0,c,h; n<l; n++){
      if(i !== n){
        c = a[n]; h = [];
        for(let v of c){
          if(inArray(v, b))h.push(v);
        }
        if(h.length === q)r.push(...h);
      }
    }
  }
  return Math.min(...r);
}
const sample1 = [6,3,1,5,2], sample2 = [2,3,4,5,6], sample3 = [4,5,6,7,8];
console.log(least(sample1, sample2, sample3));
```

Comment: "For the assignment I need to limit my built in functions to indexOf and .length."